# Can't populate listbox with strings dynamically

Tags: c#, wpf, dynamic, listbox, populate

I'm trying to populate a WPF `ListBox` with strings in C#.
If I call the function that is populating the `ListBox`, when I initialize the class it is working. But I'm making a call from the class through a socket connection, which then returns an array of strings that is supposed to populate the `ListBox`.
I've checked and the array is returned correct, but now the function won't populate the `ListBox`.

I hope someone can help me. Thanks in advance.

Update:

Here is the code:

```
public void SetUpHoldListBoxString(String hold)
    {
        String[] tempHold = hold.Split('-');

        for (int i = 0; i < tempHold.Length; i++)
        {
            HoldList.Items.Insert(i, tempHold[i]);
        }
    }
```

And this is the listbox.

```
<ListBox Name="HoldList" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="388" Margin="10,60,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="246" SelectionChanged="SelectedHold" MouseDoubleClick="JoinHold"/>
```

Update:
The problem seems to be that the method that populates the listbox is being called from another class. Because when the method is called is stops when it comes to the line that inserts the first item. But if the method is called from the class itself it works perfectly.

Comment: Can you show the code which does NOT work?

Comment: Post your code so that someone can help you!

Comment: Is the calling code done in an event handler? It seems strange that it would work calling it yourself but not from the class handling the socket comms...

Comment: I didn't figure out the problem, but I found a way to work around the issue.... but thanks for your time, I appreciate it :)